# “You are set up” or “you are setup”

Tags: nouns, phrase-requests

“you are set up” or “you are setup” 
Which of these forms is correct in the sense of “you (or your account) is ready” ?

Comment: Up it is that you are set.

Comment: (Note that *setup* is a noun.)

Answer (score 1):

Set up seems more like an action, while setup is more of noun. "You are set up" would make more sense than "you are a setup."